# flash doesn't work on custom domain blogspot

Tags: dns, flash, blogspot

I created a blog in blogspot (satudekadefn.blogspot.com) and post a flash and it's working fine.

Then I created a custom domain for the blog (the domain is now satudekadefn.felzhiro.com) and the flash is not working anymore. I haven't change the code and wondering what went wrong for this issue. If I revert the domain to blogspot the flash is working again.

Below is the code:

```
<div id="flashContent">
   <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="satudekadefn" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="https://sites.google.com/site/satudekadefn/flash/satudekadefn.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object data="https://sites.google.com/site/satudekadefn/flash/satudekadefn.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="600" align="middle">
     <param name="movie" value="https://sites.google.com/site/satudekadefn/flash/satudekadefn.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
     <param name="play" value="true" />
     <param name="loop" value="true" />
     <param name="wmode" value="window" />
     <param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
     <param name="menu" value="true" />
     <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
     <param name="salign" value="" />
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
     <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
      <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
     </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
   </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the SWF file is sitelocked? (Contains code that says it will only work on certain websites)

Comment: I don't think so. I paste the swf file (https://sites.google.com/site/satudekadefn/flash/satudekadefn.swf) on my browser and it works fine.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but when I click that link it brings me to a site that says 'click here to download this attachment'. When I click that I see a flash file. So maybe google does something weird? Maybe try hosting it somewhere else?